Converting a difference and standard deviation into a probability that one is bigger
Suppose I have two normally distributed, independent variables $v_1$ and $v_2$ with mean and standardard deviation of $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\mu_1$, and $\mu_2$. E.g., suppose you have $v_1 = 10\pm3$ and $v_2 = 11\pm2$.
I want to calculate the probability, $p$, that $v_2>v_1$. For a specific example, it would be easy enough to compare percentile by percentile or use monte carlo to get an estimate of $p$.
But I wondered if there's a formula in terms of $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\mu_1$, and $\mu_2$. It would be okay for this to be an approximation, or to consider a special case where $\mu_1=\mu_2$.
Is there a simple way to think about this?
For example, here is a simple spreadsheet that generates a matrix of values of each percentile and simply counts how often one beats the other. It's an approximation, but probably pretty close.
Here, we see that for the example I gave above ($v_1 = 10\pm3$ and $v_2 = 11\pm2$), $P(v_2>v_1)\approx0.61$. This is simply that of the 9,801 cases (99 percentiles x 99 percentiles), $v_2>v_1$ in 5,996 of them.

The easiest way may be to consider the distribution of $v_1-v_2$, which is simple if they are independent.

As the question is currently stated, the question can't be answered.  You need some information about the joint distribution, e.g. that they are independent.

@RobertIsrael, I clarified that they are independent.

@Henry, it sounds like you have an answer. Please can you share it. Do the standard deviations just get added as the $\sqrt{\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2}$

Oh, yeah. That works. Thanks. I knew there was an easy way to look at it. Just couldn't remember it.

What happens if they're not independent, but are inversely correlated. Is the combined standard deviation then just $\mu_1+\mu_2$?

It is usual to use $\mu$ for the mean and $\sigma$ for the standard deviation i.e. $\sigma^2$ for the variance.  If they are independent $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ then their difference is $N(\mu_1-\mu_2, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$ and the standard deviation of the difference is $\sqrt{ \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$.   It is not clear what you mean by "inversely correlated", but if you mean a correlation of $-1$ then the standard deviation of the difference is $|\sigma_1-\sigma_2|$.

More generally, if the correlation is $\rho$ then the standard deviation of the difference is $\sqrt{ \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2 +2\rho \sigma_1\sigma_2}$,  If they are jointly bivariate normally distributed then their difference is also normally distributed.
